# SWRL : ^ not work on protege 4.3

Tags: owl, protege, swrl

I'm trying to add a SWRL rule to protege using conjuction sign `^` but Protege 4.3 does not approve that sign.

This issue is also present for swrl buildins such as `swrlb:lessThanOrEqual`.

[image: Screenshot]

What's wrong with `^`? May I use `,` instead?

Answer (score 1):

The terms in the Protege SWRL editor are separated by commas, not ^. See, for instance, the screenshots in my answer to [SWRL rules in protege 3.4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21243879/1281433).

> whats wrong with ^ ? may i use , instead ?

That the answer, yes.  I'm not sure what prevented you from trying it in your own running Protege, though.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i tried to conform [SWRL documentation](https://www.w3.org/Submission/SWRL) . but it seems protege rule editor syntax is different and i don't know where to study about swrl syntax in protege 4.3?! up now i know `^` should be `,` and `swrlb:lessThanOrEqual (?y, ?c)` should be `lessThanOrEqual (?y, ?c)` .  but i cant use `swrlb:pow` or even `pow` .i hope there is a documentation

Comment: @alex Protege 5.0 is already released. Please use this version which also comes with latest SWRL API which is maintained by Martin O'Connor.

Comment: @AKSW yes your right . protege 5 seems to have no problem with swrl syntax