# In Pellet (Openllet) and Jena, how to change SWRL rules?

Tags: jena, swrl, pellet

I have to run two sets of rules sequencely. Firstly, I run a set of rules, and get some results from the reasoning. Secondly, I want to run another set of rules based on the results from the first step. Can anyone tell me how to do so in JENA?

Thank you!

Yang

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using SWRL with Jena and Pellet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357836/using-swrl-with-jena-and-pellet).

Comment: Jena model -> apply reasoning -> new inf model -> apply reasoning. But shouldn't happen this implicitly by just using all rules? I mean, usually some fixpoint iteration is done until no new triples will be inferred.